# How to stop Androids' Browser from scrolling back

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, jquery-mobile, mobile-webkit

I'm working on a jquery-mobile app and have run into a bit of an issue; I'd like to use jquery's animate() for a gentle scroll "back to top" of my app's pages.

The following code snippet works great in all but one of my test browsers.  Chrome & Firefox on desktop, Safari on iPhone, and Firefox Beta on Android are all good. The default Android Browser (webkit-mobile IIRC) scrolls back to the anchor when the animation is complete.

```
$("a[href='#top']").live('click', function() {
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow", function() {
        // anim complete
        setTimeout(function() { // not needed, attempt to brute-force
          window.scrollTo(0,0);
          alert('foo'); // <- Android scrolls back to anchor after showing alert
        }, 50);
    });
});
```

Can anyone suggest a) what's causing the Android Browser to scroll back and/or b) suggest a workaround?  If it makes a difference the device I'm testing with at the moment is running Android 2.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the documentation on an unrelated issue, I stumbled upon the [$.mobile.silentScroll()](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) method - designed apparently for just this situation.

Here's my initial brain-dead workaround:

```
function scrollToTop() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    scrollPos -= 60;
    if (scrollPos < 1) { scrollPos = 1; }
    $.mobile.silentScroll(scrollPos);
    if (scrollPos > 1) { setTimeout(scrollToTop, 60); }
}

$("a[href='#top']").live('vclick', function() {
    scrollToTop();
    return false;
});
```

Still curious as to why Android Browser wants to scroll back to the anchor in the original form.

Comment: Did it work? I'm having the same issues and want to know if you found a better solution or if this one is just perfect. Cheers

Comment: I didn't see anything better; this isn't perfect by any means, but it worked for what I needed at the time. If you do find a better solution, I'd love to hear about it. :)